# Updating and Validating email field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im creating a update page, where the user can change his email, but it needs a password confirmation for that. But before this, it needs some kind of validation, first to check if the current email is correct and also if the new email is available to be saved, and after the password is correct than be updated.

But im having some trouble in making the request, validation, can someone tell me if this is correct? (dont mind the dd i putted, is just for testing).

```
$user = Auth::user();
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'current_email'     => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'. $user->id,
            'email'             => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'verify_password'   => 'required|min:6'
        ));


        //Verify information user before updating
        if($user->email != $request->current_email){
            dd("Current Email is not the same");
        }

        if($user->password != bcrypt($request->verify_password)){
            dd("Password incorrect, will not update");
        }


        dd("update, is ok now");
```

Comment: Don't mind me asking this.`$user->validate` or `$this->validate`?

Comment: @KelvinKyaw $this->validate is the correct syntax. :)

Comment: So, where your `validate()` function?

Comment: @KelvinKyaw It's not mine. I'm just here trying to figure out what's wrong with the code. `validate` method comes from laravel. It's a form request validation. You can check it here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation :)

Comment: @LaraBelle I thought that you model have validate function that inside like `Validator::make($request,$rule);`

Comment: @KelvinKyaw That's not mine. I don't know also what's the error. So, it's hard for us to debug his problem. Anyway, I think someone already overcome this problem. I hope someone will help him.

Comment: @KelvinKyaw the base controller in Laravel has a trait called `ValidatesRequests`. That is where `$this->validate` comes from.

Comment: @JRLambert Thanks J. I was confused with `Validator::make`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write this in your console.

```
php artisan make:provider ValidationServiceProvider
```

Then replace your `app\Providers\ValidationServiceProvider` with

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  /**
   * Bootstrap any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function boot() {
    Validator::extend('old_password', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
      return auth()->validate([
        'email' => auth()->user()->email,
        'password' => $value
      ]);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Register the service provider.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function register() {
    //
  }
}
```

Now add it to **providers** in `config\app.php`, like

```
App\Providers\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
```

Now replace your method definition with

```
$user = auth()->user();

$validator = Validator::make($request, array(
              'current_email'     => 'required|email|exists:users,email,id,'. $user->id,
              'email'             => 'required|email|unique:users',
              'verify_password'   => 'required|min:6|old_password'
             ));

if($validator->fails()) {
  return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}

dd("Good to go!!!");
```

1. First of all I have replaced your **current_email** `unique` validation with `exists`. Why? Have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists)
2. The method I have used here for validation is called Custom Validation. More details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Let me know if you face any issues :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have will work, but there are a couple of things that I would recommend.

First, you already have the `$request`, so you should get the `user` from that. While `Auth::user()` and `$request->user()` do return the same thing, the later will not require the use of a facade and therefore is a little quicker.

Second, I would validate the before you validate the request body. It doesn't make sense to spend the resources validating the `$request` if the password is not correct.

Third, you can put your `$user->email == $request->current_email` check in the validation using the [`exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists) rule. It would be something like `"exists:users,email,id,$user->id"`.

How you display the errors will be up to how the request is being done. Take a look at the [Displaying Validation Errors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) section for submitting a form and the [AJAX Requests and Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#quick-ajax-requests-and-validation) for AJAX requests.